# How to render Index() action from the other project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

There are two web projects in my solution. 
The first (**A**) of them is assigned as a startup project. The second (**B**) displays a table with data through the action Index().
It is necessary to display the action Index() from the project (**B**) in the project (**A**).
I tried to do it through these methods, but when the action in the project controller (**A**) works to the end, the view engine tries to find view not in the project (**A**), but in project (**B**)

```
Html.Action ("Index", "Home")
Html.RenderAction ("Index", "Home")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are two web projects, you can't display content of one project on another project. If you think of the deployable artefacts, each is a separate web site, completely unaware of each other.

To achieve this you are going to need to call one website from the other. 
Ideally using a [client side ajax load](http://api.jquery.com/load/). You can use jQuery to do this:

```
$("#mydiv").load("https://projecta.example.com/ajax/mypage");
```

or a relative URL if that's how your projects are structured

```
$("#mydiv").load("/projecta/ajax/mypage");
```

Comment: It was assumed that each individual web project will be as a separate module of the overall system. Perhaps I initially chose the wrong architecture.

Comment: It's not a bad architecture, it seperates logically separate components, reduces code complexity and reduces the risk of releases. However, you'll need to think about how you pass state around the system, and how it all comes together in the main website.